# slow query without db_owner role

Tags: sql-server-2012

We have a query that hits multiples views. This query is running under 20 seconds when the user has the db_owner role. As soon we change db_owner role to db_datareader, it take around 2 minutes and 30 seconds for the same query.

We get the same result when we put the query inside a stored procedure with recompile option. We also tried to reassign the parameters of the stored procedure to internal variables in case of parameter sniffing, same result.

The execution plan seems to be the same with and without the db_owner permission. When we consult sys.dm_exec_cached_plans, we see the usecounts incrementing on the same cache plan.

We were able to reproduce this issue on three computers.

Our test scenario is:

1. We open a SSMS with an administrator user
2. We open another SSMS with a test user
3. We assign the db_owner role to the test user from the administrator session
4. We execute the query on the test user, it take 20 seconds
5. We remove the db_owner role to the test user from the administrator session
6. We execute the query on the test user without closing is current session, it take 2 minutes and 30 seconds

Our SQL version is SQL 2012 SP 2

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) 
May 14 2014 18:34:29 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 10586: )
```

This query is for a report on our website. We will like to keep the security at a minimum level. Does somebody have an idea why it take so long for the same user without db_owner role?

Thank you!

Comment: Wild guess: Resource Governor and different resources assigned

Comment: Have you compared the actual execution plans used in steps 4 and 6 of the test scenario?

Comment: Does the behaviour change if you change the stored procedure to execute in the security context of the owner (`CREATE PROCEDURE <proc name> WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER`)?

Comment: @lad2025 We are not using Resource Governor

Comment: @Ed Harper 4 and 6 are exactly the same execution plan except for two attribute of the QueryPlan tag: CompileTime="3465" CompileCPU="3465"

Comment: @Ed Harper WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER works well. It is a good plan B. Does this solution hide the source issue?

Comment: Thank Ed Harper and lad2025 for your support

Comment: Ho well, in a view in a query, there was a function, inside of the function, there was a select to sys.columns, after we replaced sys.columns for something more appropriate, everything came back in 20 seconds. Thanks again for your feedbacks!